# Check if Laravel object has items

Tags: php, laravel, collections, count

I have to ensure that I only display a foreach loop in blade - only if there are elements in my variable.

So I need to check if my variable is
- null or not (there could be no such variable in a very dynamic blade)
- it has elements - if it is array, if it is collection, if it is a paginated collection?

So far I made this little function but it looks kinda odd and as I am not very good with Laravel I am wondering if there is already something better?

```
public static function hasItems($object) {
        if (is_null($object)) {
            return false;
        }

        //array
        if (
            is_array($object) && 
            count($object) > 0
        ) {
            return true;
        }

        //Laravel collection
        if (
            is_object($object) &&
            $object instanceof \Illuminate\Support\Collection &&
            $object->count() > 0            
        ) {
            return true;
        }

        //Laravel paginator
        if (
            is_object($object) &&
            $object instanceof \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator &&
            count($object) > 0          
        ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `isEmpty()` method [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-isempty).
Or in Blade you can use the `@forelse` directive which is basically `foreach` with an if [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#loops)

Edit 1: 
I just realized that you said you can also get null as a value.
Then a solution is:

```
forelse($var ?? [] as $varItem)

@empty

@endforelse
```